# Separar numeros de array y ordenarlos, si hay consecutivos de 0 poner X

Tags: javascript, array

- Se tiene un arreglo con un listado de números, el cual puede ser de cualquier tamaño.
- Estos se dividen en bloques con el número cero, el cual marca el inicio y final de este y otro bloque.
- Un cero al inicio y final del bloque implicaría que no hay elementos.
- Se necesitan ordenar igualmente estos bloques de forma ascendente.
- Al imprimir las secuencias deben estar separadas por un espacio.
- Si hay una secuencia de ceros al imprimirse debería representarse por una X.

  Ejemplo 1:
  [1,3,2,0,7,8,1,3,0,6,7,1]

  El resultado:
  123 1378 167

  Ejemplo 2:
  [2,1,0,0,3,4]

  El resultado:
  12X34

Creo que debo utiliar algunas funciones, tal vez recorrer con for e implementar una condicion para hallar los 0 y separar:

```
myArray = [1,3,2,0,7,8,1,3,0,6,7,1]
//Resultado 123 1378 167

myArray2 = [2,1,0,0,3,4]
// Resultado 12 X 34
 
//console.log(myArray.sort())
// [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 7, 7, 8]

myArray = myArray.join( " 0 " );

console.log(myArray + "<br />" );

myArray2.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
console.log(myArray2);
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado al momento? Recuerda que por lo menos debes de incluir un [mcve] si no quieres que tu pregunta termine cerrada. Puedes hacerlo en cualquier momento dando clic en [edit].

Answer (score 1):

Te adjunto una posible solución. Tal vez no sea la más eficiente posible pero fue la que me salió de manera rápida.

La idea es ir recorriendo el array y preguntar si el elemento actual es cero o es el último elemento del array. Si el elemento NO es cero ni el último, lo agrego a un array temporal, si el elemento es cero, ordeno inmediatamente ese array principal y lo agrego a la cadena de salida. También pregunto si el próximo es cero para añadir una X si se cumple.

El if anidado en el segundo else, es para evitar añadir un espacio extra al final de la cadena.

```js
const myArray = [1,3,2,0,7,8,1,3,0,6,7,1]
//Resultado 123 1378 167

const myArray2 = [2,1,0,0,3,4]
// Resultado 12 X 34

const myArray3 = [4,8,0,2,0,5,7,8,1,3,0,6,0,0,7,1,0]
// Resultado 48 2 13578 6 X 017

function myFunction(array){
  let salida ='';
  let temp = []
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] !== 0 && i+1 < array.length)
       temp.push(array[i])
    else{ 
       if(i+1 == array.length){
         temp.push(array[i])
         salida += temp.sort((a,b)=> a-b).join('')
       }else{
         salida += temp.sort((a,b)=> a-b).join('')+ ' ' 
         temp = [] 
       }   
       if(i+1 < array.length && array[i+1]==0)
         salida += 'X'
    }
  }
  return salida
}

console.log(myFunction(myArray))
console.log(myFunction(myArray2))
console.log(myFunction(myArray3))
```